# Getting <List> of each type in an anonymous type array variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Using a Linq query, I have returned an array of two types and am trying assign each list of types to a list variable of the given type:

Model:

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    public List<DbTable> DbTables;
    public List<Application> Applications;
}
```

Controller:

```
var ReportTablesAndSystems = (from tu in db.DbTablesUsed
                              join t in db.DbTables on tu.TableId equals t.TableId
                              join a in db.DbApplication on t.ApplicationId equals a.ApplicationId
                              where tu.ReportId == id
                              select new
                              {
                                  a,
                                  t
                              }).ToList();

ReportViewModel rvm = new ReportViewModel();

rvm.DbTables = //?????????
rvm.Applications = //??????
```

How can I set rvm.DbTables to be the list of DbTables which is held in ReportTablesAndSystems and set rvm.Applications to be the list of Applications held in ReportTablesAndSystems?

Comment: What does `ReportTablesAndSystems` contain?  I.e. a `List<T>` -- what is `T`?

Comment: {Application a, DbTable t}

Comment: Your comment makes no sense.  What type does the list contain?

Comment: `ReportTablesAndSystems.Select(x =>x.a).ToList()` ?

Comment: I think your `ReportViewModel` should only consist of one list of applications, each containing a collection of tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have returned an array of two types

That would actually be a list of an anonymous type with properties `a` of type `Application` and `t` of type `DbTable`. ;)

You can assign your two properties like this then:

```
rvm.DbTables = ReportTablesAndSystems.Select(r => r.t).ToList();
rvm.Applications = ReportTablesAndSystems.Select(r => r.a).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - simple solution!

Comment: Alternatively :
rvm.DbTables = (from r in ReportTablesAndSystems
                            select r.t).ToList()